# For a probability kernel $\mu$, why is $\left\{ (s,t):\mu(s,[0,x])<t \right\}$ a measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability kernel from a measurable space $(S,\mathscr S)$ to $([0,1],\mathscr B[0,1])$. Let $s\in S, t\in [0,1]$. I don't understand why the function$$f(s,t)=\sup \left\{x\in [0,1]:\mu(s,[0,x])<t \right\}$$ is product measurable. I don't even see why the set $\left\{ (s,t):\mu(s,[0,x])<t \right\}$ is product measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that $x \mapsto \mu(s,[0,x])$ is a monotone right-continuous function. Therefore,

$$f(s,t)> a \Leftrightarrow \mu(s,[0,a])<t$$

for any $a \in [0,1]$. In order to prove the measurability, it therefore suffices to show that the set

$$A:=\{(s,t); \mu(s,[0,a])<t\}$$

is measurable. To this end, we note that, by assumption, the mappings

$$s \mapsto \mu(s,[0,a]) \qquad \qquad t \mapsto t$$

are measurable. Since both functions only depend on one variable, this implies obviously the product measurability of both functions, i.e.

$$(s,t) \mapsto \mu(s,[0,a]) \qquad \text{and} \quad (s,t) \mapsto t$$

are measurable. Consequently,

$$(s,t) \mapsto \varphi(s,t) := \mu(s,[0,a])-t$$

is product measurable. As $A = \varphi^{-1}(-\infty,0)$, the claim follows.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!

Comment: Well explained, +1.

Comment: Questions: Why are the inequalities in the first equivalence strict? Where exactly does right-continuity come in?
It looks like the monotonicity of the map $x \mapsto \mu(s,[0,x])$ suffices to write the first equivalence with weak inequalities.. Is it enough?

Comment: @Sai What do you mean by "weak inequalities"?

Comment: replacing "$<$" with "$\leq$" etc.

Comment: @Sai No, that doesn't work. In general, $f(s,t) \geq a$ does *not* imply $\mu(s,[0,a]) \leq t$. The first equivalence is in fact due to the right-continuity (and monotonicity).

Comment: My attempt:
$f(s,t)>a\implies \exists b\in (a,f(s,t))$ such that $\mu(s,[0,b])<t$ now taking the limit over such $b$'s we have due to right continuity $t\overset{?}{>} \lim_{b\rightarrow a^+}\mu(s,[0,b])=\mu(s,[0,a])$

Comment: @Sai Note that taking the limit does not preserve strict inequalities (i.e. $a_n < a$ does *not* imply $\lim a_n <a$). But actually, this implication follows simply from the monotonicity, as  (using your notation) $$\mu(s,[0,a]) \leq \mu(s,[0,b]) < t.$$